# Process element depending on position of preceding sibling

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way to handle an element `<list_x>` depending on the position of certain nodes on the `preceding-sibling`-axis?

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <text/>
        <text/>
        <text/>
        <list_num_start/>
        <list_num/>
        <list_num/>
        <list_x/>
        <text/>
        <text/>
        <text/>
        <list_square_start/>
        <list_square/>
        <list_square/>
        <list_x/>
    </root>
```

Template:

```
<xsl:template match="list_x">
    <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position(preceding-sibling::list_num_start[last()]) &lt; position(preceding-sibling::list_square_start[last()])">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/ol&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>...</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately `position()` does not allow any arguments.

Output should be:

```
<root>
    <text/>
    <text/>
    <text/>
    <ol>
        <li class="list_num_start"/>
        <li class="list_num"/>
        <li class="list_num"/>
        <li class="list_x"/>
    </ol>
    <text/>
    <text/>
    <text/>
    <ul>
        <li class="list_square_start"/>
        <li class="list_square"/>
        <li class="list_square"/>
        <li class="list_x"/>
    </ul>
</root>
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The output that you show is not well-formed XML and cannot be produced by XSL transformation. -- Please explain in plain language the logic you want to apply here. A non-working code is no substitute for an explanation.

Comment: the code was considered as an example. The question is how to process elements depeding on certain preceding elements on the `preceding-sibling`-axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
  <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::list_num_start[1]/preceding-sibling::*) &lt; 
             count(preceding-sibling::list_square_start[1]/preceding-sibling::*)">
```

This counts the element before the one you are looking for.

I changed `list_num_start[last()]` to `list_num_start[1]` because I assume you are looking for the element list_num_start direct before the current one.